# Notepad++ Execution Path

Tags: path, directory, notepad++

I have several shortcuts for running scripts with different commands. For example:

`<Command name="node-js-run" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="119">cmd /K node "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"</Command>`

(in my user's appdata/roaming directory.)

However, when a script has run, the cmd window exits at

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++>`

This is annoying as I may wish to do something else with the script without having to re-navigate.

Is there a way to tweak the command so that when the script ends, the current directory of the cmd window is the same as the script it just ran please?

Comment: Note the `CD ... &&` command within the "Run as command" part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22176076/546871, but change the `cmd  /C` to be `cmd /K`.

Comment: Thanks, that works.