# Notepad++ multiple run commands

Tags: command, notepad++, exec

How can I run `cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"` followed by `path/to/python.exe -i "$(FILE_NAME)"` in the notepad++ `run` dialogue (F5) please?

I don't want to use nppexec because I want the program to run in the windows cmd window not the npp console. Also I specifically need to cd into the folder rather than relying on the default behaviour. I've tried separating the commands with semi-colons and commas, but no joy.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22176076/546871 for something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DOS/Windows command shell, you separate multiple commands on a single line using the ampersand character (&):

```
cmd /c cd \ptools & dir /s /b *.awk & pause
```

This changes to the \ptools directory, then shows every AWK file and waits for a key to be pressed.

In your case:

```
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & path\to\python.exe -i "$(FILE_NAME)"
```