# An easier way to run Fortran on Notepad++

Tags: fortran, notepad++

Now I am writing Fortran on Notepad++, and every time I want to execute my program (namely, test), I would open cmd, change the path to current dictionary, type `gfortran test.f90 -o test`, finally type `test.exe` again. I wonder if there is a simpler way for execution, so that I can run Fortran with the click of a mouse.

I have tried running this line in Notepad++

```
gfortran "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"
```

It will generate test.f90.exe file and I have to open cmd to execute it every time, which still takes some effort.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. I removed your last line as it as a poll question. This site is not for polls but for answering a well-defined question. Please explain how you tried to run the mentioned line in the editor and what exactly happened.

Comment: There are many text editirs with fewer or more coding features. For example, in the editor I used most often, a Linux one, even if available in some Windows form as well, I have an integrated terminal window and I run the commands in that terminal manually. I also have VScode with more tools, but I run the commands in the integrated terminal as well.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174577/how-do-get-my-script-file-to-console-via-notepad-external-command/22176076#22176076 .

Comment: After reading your last edit, I think that the instructions linked by AdrianHHH might help you. Try `gfortran "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe" && "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"` or something similar.

Comment: You should be able to keep the cmd window open and pointing at the right directory if you start it from Windows. Then any editor/IDE can alter the source code and either build the file for you or you can recall the compile line or execute a make file in the cmd window. TBH I prefer [SIlverFrost fortran aka Salford](https://www.silverfrost.com/) for developing on the rare ocaissions I still have to do it. There is a free evaluation version with a time delay on start of execution as well as a full paid for version.

Comment: Thank those who made their comment and it helps a lot! This little thing indeed makes my coding more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Open Fortran file on Notepad++, click Run -> Run... then write this line in the window

```
cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && gfortran "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe" && "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"
```

and Run, the file will execute and run in the command line automatically. You can also click Save... and give a name and shortcut for this command to do this without even a click.

`cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"` is for open cmd in the desired folder, and `gfortran "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"` to generate .exe file for the program, finally `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"` runs the .exe file.